Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't
I have a flutter app that is working fine for android. I created an ios project and am trying to run it but am running into the error below:
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/getwidget-4.0.0/lib/components/button/gf_button.dart:579:34: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.


Error launching application on iPhone.


I tried flutter doctor, flutter pub cache clean and flutter pub upgrade. No matter what I do, I still get the error. Even tried changing the version of getwidget in the pubspec.yaml but no luck. Is there a version mismatch or unsupported package that I am missing?
The pubspec.yaml dependencies are:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  provider: ^6.1.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  get: ^4.6.5
  http: ^1.2.1
  fluttertoast: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  floating_snackbar: ^1.0.3+1
  firebase_core: ^2.32.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
  connectivity_plus: ^6.0.3
  intl: ^0.19.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  upgrader: ^8.4.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  getwidget: ^4.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  awesome_snackbar_content: ^0.1.3
  device_info_plus: ^10.1.0

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/appicon.png"
  android: true

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/translations/
    - assets/animation/


Flutter doctor returns no issue found.
I am expecting the app to successfully compile for ios.

As this error is in the dart code, I am surprised that you can build for Android but not iOS, but it is an issue with the repo - https://github.com/ionicfirebaseapp/getwidget/issues/356

Thanks for the response. Yea android seems to be working. Is there a workaround to this? Can I use an older version to get around this and get it to build for ios as well?

The incident I linked to had some fixes that the reporter created.  It's open source, so you can fork the repo, fix the code and submit a PR
